# C# and Linq: Generating SQL Backup/Restore From Code

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, smo

I'm working with a C# and Linq to SQL Winforms app and needed to integrate backup and restores through the program. I used SMO and got it working pretty smoothly. The issue, however, is that the app is deployed using ClickOnce, which I like very much - but since I had to include the dll's the download size jumped from 3mb => 15mb. I know they've only got to download it once, but it also sucks for me as Visual Studio 2010 seems to upload the dll's every time and that takes a while on AT&T broadband (eh).

So, anyone have any suggestion on how I can work out an effective backup/restore solution without using SMO objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just fire plain ol'sql at the box via ado commands

Comment: I like the idea of SPROC's, and should have thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedures to do backup and restore in lieu of SMO.  There are a number of samples available on the web, [including this one](http://forums.asp.net/t/993797.aspx).